# How to automatically reorder named function arguments with Resharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper

When reordering arguments in a function signature, callers do not get updated (unless specifically using the Change signature method in Resharper) and continue to compile fine with the old order. This is not a problem semantically but may look a bit messy when many callers end up having different argument orders.

Is there any way with Resharper - or any other tool - to automatically reorder named parameters solutionwide so that they can perfectly match the function signature?

This seems like a nice refactoring function that would make the code look more consistent, and to which I don't see any possible side effect or negative aspect, much like standardizing other cosmetic aspects across a solutions.

Comment: Have you tried the "Change signature" refactor option on the method name? It will fix callers, as long as callers are in the same solution.

Comment: I know, but I am looking for a way to do this automatically for all functions in the solutions, which would take time if I had to do it  manually (thousands of functions spread across many files).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen obviously he has, since it's right there in the post.

Answer (score 1):

- Did you know Ctrl-F6 is the usual shortcut for Change Signature?
- Did you know you can write R# plugins? Likely, this would not be a very large task

  - see e.g. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/plugins/index.jsp

Might have some drawbacks too:

Ordering of parameters often conveys information to the developer: it might show some logical grouping of information, e.g.

```
 Foo(foo: 3,
     zyx: "hello",
     flurb: null,    // these 3 from the config file

     val: 42);       // from the input xml
```

Comment: Why would it be a bad idea to ensure callers use named arguments in the same order as in the original function signature? I am not talking about renaming parameters per se, if this is what you feared.
Thanks for the 2 suggestions though.

Comment: Would you believe I missed that in the title? Anyways, edited